# Internal compiling with proper encoding?

Tags: java, encoding, compiler-construction, internal

I have a program that writes a string to a .java file, uses `javax.tools` to compile that .java file into a .class file, and I then use a modified ClassLoader to attempt to get a `Runnable` instance of the class (by turning it into a byte array and using `ClassLoader.defineClass` to get an instance). But.., I'm having a problem. When the program attempts to get an instance of the class, it notices that it was not compiled the right way. I get a `ClassFormatError` that reads `Incompatible magic value 1885430635 in class file <Unknown>`. Here is my (fairly sloppy, at the moment) code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.security.SecureClassLoader;

public class EnhancedClassLoader extends SecureClassLoader
{
    public Object createObjectFromFile(String fileName) throws 
    InstantiationException, IOException, IllegalAccessException
    {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        definePackage("compClassPack", null, null, null, null, null, null, file.toURI().toURL());
        byte[] classBytes = null;
        //ReadFileToByteArray
        {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            int size = (int)file.length();
            classBytes = new byte[size];
            int offset = 0;
            int readed;
            while (offset < size && (readed = fis.read(classBytes, offset, size - offset)) != -1)
            {
                offset += readed;
            }
        fis.close();
        }
        Class<?> clazz = defineClass(null, classBytes, 0, classBytes.length);
            //The error is thrown here! ^^^

        return clazz.newInstance();
    }
}
```

.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.tools.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
    {
        File file = new File("Sample.java");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        String code =
                "package compClassPack;\n" +
                "public class Sample implements Runnable\n" +
                "{\n" +
                "    public Sample(){}\n\n" +
                "    public static void main(String[] args)\n" +
                "    {\n" +
                "        new Sample().run();\n" +
                "    }\n\n" +
                "    public void run()\n" +
                "    {\n" +
                "        System.out.println(\"It worked! :D\");\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "}";

        for(byte ch : code.getBytes())
        {
            if((char)ch!='\n')
                bw.write((char)ch);
            else
                bw.newLine();
        }
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();

        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();
        StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);
        Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = fileManager.getJavaFileObjects(file);
        JavaCompiler.CompilationTask ct = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, diagnostics, null, null, compilationUnits);
        ct.call();

        for (Diagnostic<? extends JavaFileObject> diagnostic : diagnostics.getDiagnostics())
            System.out.format("Error on line %d in %d%n",
                    diagnostic.getLineNumber(),
                    ((FileObject)diagnostic.getSource()).toUri());

        fileManager.close();

        EnhancedClassLoader loader = new EnhancedClassLoader();
        Runnable runs = (Runnable) loader.createObjectFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
        runs.run(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your byte array is not valid bytecode. If it were, it would begin with the magic string (hex) `0xCAFEBABE`. Instead, your first bytes are `1885430635` (decimal), which is hex `0x7061636b`, which read one byte at a time gives the ASCII characters `pack`, which is just the beginning of the package declaration.

In other words, you are trying to load a text file as if it were bytecode, and obviously Java can't construct any class from such a byte stream.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that.. Is there anyway that you know of that would allow me to do what I'm wanting?

Comment: [Here](http://mike-java.blogspot.it/2008/03/java-6-compiler-api-tutorial.html) is a very simple tutorial